# How to calculate exact year, month and day between two dates in vc++/MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

In my application i have to find out exact year, month and day between two dates.  I tried with below snip.  but answer is not correct.  I used CTime for from to to dates.  The result is obtained in CTimeSpan class.  CTimeSpan has member function such as GetDays.  We shall find out year, month and day from Total Days, but answer is not correct.  Is any way to do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For some purposes, the COleDateTime and COleDateTimeSpan classes work better (in particular, they work over a much longer time span).

Comment: CTimeSpan and COleDateTime are not much different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no common function to do that.

My idea would be:

```
  COleDateTime date1(1979,12,31,0,0,0),
               date2(2004,10,01,0,0,0);

  // Get the normal differences
  int iYears = date2.GetYear()-date1.GetYear(),
      iMonths = date2.GetMonth()-date1.GetMonth(),
      iDays = date2.GetDay()-date1.GetDay();

  // Problematic underflow of days. 
  if (iDays<0)
  {
    // One month less
    --iMonths;
    // Advance from the start date until we reach the 1st of next month
    for (iDays=0; (date1+COleDateTimeSpan(iDays,0,0,0)).GetDay()!=1; ++iDays)
      ;

    // Now get the days from the 1st of the second date to the desired date.
    iDays += static_cast<int>((COleDateTime(date2.GetYear(),date2.GetMonth(),1,0,0,0)-date2).GetTotalDays());
  }     

  // underflow of months
  if (iMonths<0)
  {
    --iYears;
    iMonths +=12;
  }
```

Comment: I will try your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `CTimeSpan::GetTotalDays()` function in the [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ay6ws8h3.aspx).

Anyway, the `GetTotalHours / GetTotalMinutes` functions return the number of **Complete** Hours/Minutes and does not fully represent the TimeSpan value; the best way would be to use [GetTotalSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/081ks6xz.aspx) and convert it as necessary.